# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Я решаю вот такую задачу на Stepik: В dataframe с именем my_stat сохранены данные с 4 колонками: session_value, group, time, n_users.В переменной session_value замените все пропущенные значения на нули. В переменной n_users замените все отрицательные значения на медианное значение переменной n_users (без учета отрицательных значений, разумеется). Вот то что я написал (я новичок в pandas):

```
import pandas as pd    

my_stat['session_value'].query('session_value == None') = 0
my_stat['n_users'].query('n_users < 0') = my_stat['n_users'].mean()
```

Но при отправке ответа я получаю такую ошибку:

```
  File "jailed_code", line 23
    my_stat.query('session_value == None') = 0
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: обычно это значит что до этой строки присутствует синтаксическая ошибка (забыли скобку закрыть, ошибка в строке). проследите внимательно код до 23 строки

Comment: @Pigeoncatcher, это сообщение об ошибке _не может_ появиться, если забыли закрыть скобку. Оно появляется только в том случае, если человек пытается присвоить значение вызову. Это не "грамматическая", а синтаксическая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Суть ошибки в том, что вы пытаетесь присвоить значение **вызову функции**.

Пример для воспроизведения ошибки:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
sum(lst) = 10
# SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

---

Для заполнения `NaN`/`None` существуют специальные методы [Series.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)  и [DataFrame.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [206]: df
Out[206]:
   a  b    c
0  1  2  NaN
1  4  5  6.0
2  7  8  NaN

In [207]: df["c"] = df["c"].fillna(0)

In [208]: df
Out[208]:
   a  b    c
0  1  2  0.0
1  4  5  6.0
2  7  8  0.0
```